# Java Swing JTable ListSelectionModel, wrong value of leadSelectionIndex

Tags: java, swing

In one of the apps that I have been supporting there is a piece of code responsible for handling selected/unselected rows in a Jtable. It does so in a `ListSelectionListener` based on the selectionModels leadIndex - `ListSelectionModel.getLeadSelectionIndex()`.

In the Jtable implementation, when the table's sort order is changed - the selection is cached in terms of the tables model `Jtable.cacheSelection()` and then resored in `Jtable.restoreSelection()`. When the selection is cached, the leadSelectionIndex is converted to model:

```
modelIndex = convertRowIndexToModel(sortEvent,
viewSelection.getLeadSelectionIndex());
SwingUtilities2.setLeadAnchorWithoutSelection(
modelSelection, modelIndex, modelIndex);
```

When restored, it is converted back:

```
if (viewLeadIndex != -1 && !modelSelection.isSelectionEmpty()) {
    viewLeadIndex = convertRowIndexToView(viewLeadIndex);
}
SwingUtilities2.setLeadAnchorWithoutSelection(
    viewSelection, viewLeadIndex, viewLeadIndex);
```

However, after one fix in the JDK http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8032874, when the selection is empty the lead index is not converted back to a view value and stays as a model value.

This causes a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the example code below, because the table is also filtered and the model has a different number of elements than the view.

The scenario to reproduce this problem is: select the second row, sort the table, clear selection and sort the table again.

For now I was able to work around this problem by storing the last selected row in a separate field, however my question is:

- Can we actually use the leadIndex or is it broken by design?
- Can this be considered as a bug in swing or would you say that it is just a wrong use of the API?
- Is there some other, better way to get the indexes of changed selected/unselected rows?

  ```
  package javatest;

  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
  import javax.swing.RowFilter;
  import javax.swing.RowSorter;
  import javax.swing.SortOrder;
  import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
  import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
  import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

  /**
   * Test frame.
   */
  public class JavaTest {
      public static void main(String args[]){
          JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("test frame");
          mainFrame.setSize(200,200);
          JTable testTable = new JTable();
          DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] {"column1", "column 2"}, 0);
          tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {"abc", "abc"});
          tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {"abc11", "abc1"});
          tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {"abc12", "abc1"});
          tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {"abc2", "abc2"});
          testTable.setModel(tableModel);

          TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(testTable.getModel());
          List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(25);
          sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
          sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
          sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("abc1", 0));
          testTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

          testTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
          testTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener( selectionEvent  -> {
              if (!selectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                  System.out.println("lead index " + testTable.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex());
                  int viewIndex = testTable.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
                  int modelIndex = testTable.convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndex);
                  System.out.println("model index " + modelIndex);
              }
          });

          JButton sortButton = new JButton("switch sort");
          sortButton.addActionListener((actionEvent) -> {
              testTable.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
          });

          JButton clearButton = new JButton("clear selection");
          clearButton.addActionListener((actionEvent) -> {
              testTable.clearSelection();
          });


          mainFrame.getContentPane().add(sortButton);
          mainFrame.getContentPane().add(clearButton);
          mainFrame.getContentPane().add(testTable);
          mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
  ```